# python loop go to previous string under if condiction

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

I have a for loop to handle data from the input
how can I when  it found the condition to start the index line where it subtract two line  before it

```
# this is the data sample

Candra Insley
Ivette Ralston
Florentina Bohon
Natalie Underhill
Shoshana Risinger
Melony Hulsey
Klara Warren
Corrina Broderick
Susana Vitti
Susy Seidman
Chris Deen
Mason Nebel
Tawanda Riccio
Shameka Schmitmeyer
Robert Longacre
Floria Padro
Julius Gelman
Kyung Barnard
Freida Manville
Wendy Bolduc
```

here is the code

```
status = request.form['data']
  status = str(status).split('\n')
  for i in status:
    if len(i) < 2:
      continue
    print i
    data = i[0]
    condition = 'Shameka Schmitmeyer'
    if condition in data:
      print 'found it'
      condition = ''
      i -= 2 # here it will subtract the current data index 2 it will go back two line to this "Mason Nebel" data and start the for from it and continue
    print data
```

```
#output it should be like

Candra Insley
Ivette Ralston
Florentina Bohon
Natalie Underhill
Shoshana Risinger
Melony Hulsey
Klara Warren
Corrina Broderick
Susana Vitti
Susy Seidman
Chris Deen
Mason Nebel
Tawanda Riccio
found it
Shameka Schmitmeyer
```

## here when the condition is true it will go back two line and continue from "Mason Nebel" this value

here how it looks when it continues

```
Mason Nebel
Tawanda Riccio
Shameka Schmitmeyer
Robert Longacre
Floria Padro
Julius Gelman
Kyung Barnard
Freida Manville
Wendy Bolduc
```

how to do it with for

### if it possible

or

- while loop

or

### what is the solution for this

hope this is clear to understand

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but you should be able to change the current loop variable like that if you switch to a while loop.

Comment: cool how can i do this with while loop

Comment: You should really fix your formatting, this is hard to follow. I'm not sure what you are asking too, what is the input to your problem and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

this is can be don buy while loop

```py
      status = request.form['data']
      status = str(status).split('\n')

      i = 0
      while i <= len(status):

        element = status[i]
        if len(status[i]) < 2:
          continue

        datalist = element.strip().split('|')
        print(datalist)
 
        data = datalist[0]
        condition = 'Shameka Schmitmeyer'

        if condition in data:
          print('found it')
          condition = ''
          i -=2

        print(data)
        i +=1
```

## output

```
Candra Insley
Ivette Ralston
Florentina Bohon
Natalie Underhill
Shoshana Risinger
Melony Hulsey
Klara Warren
Corrina Broderick
Susana Vitti
Susy Seidman
Chris Deen
Mason Nebel
Tawanda Riccio
found it
Shameka Schmitmeyer
Mason Nebel
Tawanda Riccio
Shameka Schmitmeyer
Robert Longacre
Floria Padro
Julius Gelman
Kyung Barnard
Freida Manville
Wendy Bolduc
```